# WooCommerce Email style - remove default styling

Tags: php, css, wordpress, hook, woocommerce

When generating customer emails, WooCommmerce defines a set of tags [here](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-email.php#L339) for which they apply a default hardcoded style.

```php
/**
 * style_inline_tags function.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param array $tags
 * @return array
 */
function style_inline_tags($tags) {
    return array_unique( array_merge( $tags, array( 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'a', 'img' ) ) );
}
```

I need to change this style to match the rest of the email (`Arial` → `Lucida Grande`) so I want to eliminate all of this list so **nothing** gets the default look. I tried cutting these out in the plugin's files to make sure that's what I need and sure enough it worked. But at every update, I have to patch the WooCommerce code.

Based on [Add hooks for overriding default email inline styles](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/pull/3653) and [Overriding email inline styles](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/3597) I'm trying to write a filter hook to remove these tags from the array and I can't get it to work.

This is the code I added to the end of my theme's `functions.php`

```php
/**
 * Kill defaults
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_style_inline_tags', 'kill_defaults');

function kill_defaults( $tags ) {
    $tags = array();
    return $tags;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
// WooCommerce Emails - Kill default inline styling

function kill_defaults($tags) {
    return array();
}

add_filter('woocommerce_email_style_inline_tags', 'kill_defaults', 20 );
```

This was executed too soon and thus got overwritten by the plugin afterwards. Adding the priority argument `20` to the `add_filter` function seems to have fixed it.